# How can I get a docker container to expose a port while blocking the internet at large?

Tags: docker, networking

I want to run a docker container that has no access to the outside internet.  I've been using `--network=none` for this successfully.  But now I want to host a web server from that container, and access it from outside.  When I try, I find that the port mapping is totally ignored:

```
$ docker run --rm -it -p 8000:8000 --network=none python bash
# python -m http.server
Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8000 (http://0.0.0.0:8000/) ...
```

Now from outside the container:

```
$ docker port 981f253788ad 
$ curl localhost:8000
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8000: Connection refused
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using a custom network with `--internal` option and then attaching your container to this network:

```
$ docker network create --internal internal-network
$ docker run --rm -it -p 8000:8000 --network=internal-network python bash
```

Comment: Tried that, same thing happens.  The port is not really exposed.

Comment: Ah, correction: with an `--internal` network, the container gets an IP I can hit directly.  Exposing the port with `-p 8000:8000` still doesn't work, but I can hit the internal port on that IP and it works fine.  Thanks!