# How to expose ports whilst blocking internet?

Tags: podman

I'm trying to block a podman container from having internet / network access, while allowing access to its exposed ports.

The first part seems to be easy: assign an [internal](https://docs.podman.io/en/latest/markdown/podman-network-create.1.html#internal) network.

This internal network prevents exposed ports from working (connection refused). This might be by design, the documentation is quite sparse.

[A similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54239146) for docker was solved by accessing the internal IP directly. This does not work, as the internal IP is not visible on the host.

Any ideas?

Comment: This is my understanding of the matter. (I'm not 100% certain). If your software in the container supports [socket activation](http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/socket-activation.html) (see also [sd_listen_fds() man page](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/sd_listen_fds.html)), it might be possible in the future to set up a Systemd service with a TCP socket and start Podman with `ExecStart=podman run --network none ...`. Podman support for socket activation is not working right now (Podman version 3.2) but will hopefully be fixed.